# Derivative of a piecewise function with x=0

Tags: calculus

Let

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases} e^{-x^{-2}} & \text{if } x>0 \\ 
0 & \text{if } x \leqslant 0 \end{cases} $$

How can I find the derivative of this function in x=0? Will it be 0 for every derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can prove that the derivatives of $f$ always writes as $f(x)\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials. Then taking limit gives that all the derivatives at $x=0$ are equal to 0.

It's the typical example used to show that a function's Taylor expansion is not always equal to the function itself